# Calculus and kinematics problem

Tags: calculus, kinematics

> The tunnelling speed of a machine is shown is modelled as $$v=\frac{k}{s}$$ where k
> is the constant with the units $m^2/hr$ and $s$ is the length of the
> tunnel already dugout.
>
> I am to find a reasonable lower and upper bound for the **time it
> takes to dig 5 meters** when **1 meter is already dugout** and $k=2$.

My attempt:

So I need to find time and I can do that by:
$$v=\frac{k}{s}$$
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{k}{s}$$

Rearranging and integrating:

$$\int(s)ds = k\int dt$$
$$\frac{s^2}{2}=kt$$
$$t=\frac{s^2}{2k}$$

$k = 2$, therefore:
$$t=\frac{s^2}{4}$$

$1 m$ was already dugout, and the machine moves $5m$ more. Therefore, time from $s=1$ to $s=6$ is:
$$t=\frac{6^2}{4}-\frac{1^2}{4}=8.75 hours$$

However, I doubt the correctness of this.

Comment: It seems correct to me

Comment: Its correct, the units add up. $m^2/hr$ is defining the change in some cross-sectional area (already defining the relative speed of the **change in the area**). While "s", which is assumed to be in _metres_, seems to be defining the linear length in terms of one-axis dimension (mostly likely how far the tunnel has been bored in a linear fashion). So the $\frac{k}{s}$ mostly like tells the linear change across the movement of the area (NOT change in the area) which is likely the same as the movement of the machine itself. Other than that your calculations look correct (unless I missed smthing).

Comment: @SnipingPoodle Yes, the $s$ is in meters and thank you for the explanation!